# NavLink not adding 'active' class attribute in a react-app

Tags: reactjs

React apps using create-react-app have this problem where NavLink doesn't add active class attribute.
Tried lots of solutions like adding exact attribute inside NavLink but none worked so far.

```
    import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

    return (
        <nav>
            <NavLink to='/user/feed'>Feed</NavLink>
            <NavLink to='/user/messages'>Messages</NavLink>
        </nav>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
activeClassName='active'
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally a solution. Run below command in your react-app directory and restart your app.

```
npm i path-to-regexp@1.7.0 -S
```